# Count sum to zero selections

Tags: combinatorics

Given a slot machine with payoff : $(-n, -n+1, \cdots,0, 1, \cdots, n+1, n)$. $n\ge2$

A random player plays for $K$ times and has $0$ win/loss in total.

How many different payoff outcome sequences there can be?

If there are two random players involved, in total they played $K$ times together, and both of them have $0$ win/loss outcome.

How many different payoff outcome sequences there can be?

The order in the outcome sequence matter.

E.g. $K=2$, $n=1$, one sequence can be $(1, -1)$, and another different sequence can be $(-1, 1)$.

Comment: Need clarification. "If for every tuple, only a single element is allowed to pick."  ?????

Comment: There are $K$ copies of the same tuple, if for every copy, randomly pick one element, I can form a length $K$ sequence.

Comment: It's the constant term in $(x^{-n}+x^{-n+1}+\cdots+x^n)^K$.

Comment: How can I derive this formula? and sorry I just added a two-player version

Comment: Are permutations different?  Example $n=1$ and $K=2$ are $(1,-1) and (-1,1)$ different?

Comment: sorry, I think it's different, but let me add more explanation for sure. it's still a sequence problem instead of ordered sequence

Comment: When $n=2$, the numbers are given by [A005191](http://oeis.org/A005191)

Comment: thanks! what's the connection between them?

Comment: Look at Gerry Myerson's earlier comment.

Comment: right, that is for one player, how can I generalize it to 2 players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gerry Myerson noted in a comment, the answer is the constant term in $$\left(x^{-n}+x^{-n+1}+\cdots+x^{n-1}+x^n\right)^K$$  To multiply this out, we pick one term from each of the $K$ factors, and calculate the product by adding the exponents.  Each choice of terms corresponds to one sequence of plays, and vice versa.

Since we are interested in the case where the player breaks even, we want the coefficient of the constant term.  To state this in terms of polynomials, we can pull out a factor of $x^{-n}$ from each term, so that we want the coefficient of $x^{nK}$ in $$\left(1+x+\cdots+x^{2n}\right)^K$$ that is, the coefficient of $x^{nK}$ in $$\left(\frac{x^{2n+1}-1}{x-1}\right)^K$$

One should be able to write down an explicit formula, by writing the denominator as $(1-x)^{-K}$ and expanding by the binomial theorem.

I did the calculation suggested above and I got $$\sum_{i=0}^L(-1)^i\binom Ki\binom {(n+1)K-(2n+1)i-1}{K-1},$$  where $$L=\left\lfloor\frac{(n+1)K-1}{2n+1}\right\rfloor$$